# Is it able to ignore/disable the first step Get source in vNext Build?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfsbuild

Here is our situation-- sometimes we need to run a vNext build without needing to pull any source code from TFS server.

But we don't want to change the workspace mappings. Is there a related setting simply **ignore or disable the get source step** in the build definition. Unlike any other task, the "*Get sources*" task added automatically when you create a new build definition, which is not able to disable or remove the task by right click it.

Any suggestion appreciated!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:**

Now you should use below to avoid syncing sources at all:

***Classic Editor:*** `agent.source.skip=true`

***YAML:***

```
steps:
- checkout: none
```

---

It's not able to directly disable/remove the  **Get Sources** task. However, you could **add a variable** to achieve it:

**`Build.SyncSources = false`**

[image]

> You can see from below screenshot, the Get Sources operation started
>   and finished without fetching the data from TFS version control

[image]

***Note:*** *This variable works with TFS 2017 and above/VSTS vNext builds*.

More detail info please take a look at this helpful [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2017/09/25/disabling-get-sources-step-in-vnext-build/).

Comment: However, this setting enforces leaving System.DefaultWorkingDirectory variable to be `undefined` which causes to `Path must be a string. Received undefined` error when, for example, trying to execute Queue Jenkins Job step

Comment: $(Build.SourcesDirectory) for instance is obviously also undefined. So if you are just looking for disabling the Get Sources step as a temporary solution for winning some time on a 100.000 files build, it may mess up with your other build steps... But this solution may be indeed applicable to other cases.

Comment: What if we only want to skip this step for a specific phase in a multi-phase build?

Comment: @itsho did you get a solution for this? I also want to disable it for one phase only.

Comment: @MehulParmar yes - see my answer below - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56374099/426315

Comment: @itsho but this will disable for all phases

Comment: @MehulParmar you are right. I've misread your question. it will be disabled for all phases. sorry about that.

Answer (score 6):

I tried using `agent.source.skip = true` (instead of `Build.SyncSources = false`),

and it seems to keep the variables.

Found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1465

Answer (score 1):

From classic editor here is the way to skip "Get Sources".

[image]

[image]