# TFS 2017 and MacAgent issues with files synch

Tags: macos, tfs

We have TFS 2017 and installed build agent on Mac, connectivity is ok, our build definition does not pull all files, added Project Collection Build Service or Project Build Service roles to code security, no luck.

Thanks

Comment: Could you check the **mappings** in the repository option of your build definition? If there are something cloaked or the setting is just not pull all files.

Comment: I am trying to map root folder, deleting workspace everytime, just does not pull all files

Comment: Could you provide some more information to help us debug this? Which version control are you using , TFVC or GIT? Are the files which not pull down steady or just randomly if you build multiple times? Have you tried some other build definition on the Mac Agent, did this only occurs on the specific build definition?

Comment: Can you share the build logs?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the issue happen always for this build definition or intermittently. Try to give your build service account enough permission such as local administrator on your Mac machine.  Make sure you have set the workspace clean=**ture**.

You could also disable the default get source steps in the build definition. And use your own script to do the get source/pull files to see if you get the same situation.  How to please follow: [Is it able to ignore/disable the first step Get source in vNext Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421482/is-it-able-to-ignore-disable-the-first-step-get-source-in-vnext-build)

Try to run the build multiple times, check if there are steady of some files which not pull down or the files are just randomly.  Check the left-over space on your Mac hard driver is sufficiently.

If all of the above still not fix the issue, suggest you reinstall/ reconfigure your Mac build agent(use  the latest version) and try again.  There is a thoroughly tutorial: **[Deploy an agent on OSX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-osx)** in official.