# How best to download source files from VSTS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to regularly download a complete set of latest code for a particular project from a VSTS account (server workspace), to a folder on a file server for readonly archiving.

Currently I log on to the web portal and click *Download as ZIP* for the selected project and save this to the file server.

But I'd like a more automated way, preferably something I can schedule to run from the file server itself which won't have Visual Studio installed or cached credentials for the online account.

Any of the following soluions would be ok:

- A permanent URL to download the latest code as a zip file
- A REST URL
  to get all latest files
- A command line tool to connect to the VSTS
  account and download all latest files for a particular project ***to a specified local folder, not the default local folder***

Nice to have:

- Option to download as ZIP or recursive folder of files
- Set files modified date as check-in time
- Remove source control binding information from the downloaded files
- Provide user credentials as part of the command line, not assume to use the default cached credentials on the machine

Answer (score 3):

You could use our tools in Visual Studio, Eclipse, or from the **command line** to keep a local copy of your source code on your machine.

More details please refer official tutorial: [Download (get) files from the Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/download-get-files-from-server?view=vsts)

Also, if you want to download your code as a zip:

You can click on any ellipsis to find the menu which contains `Download as Zip` option.

[image]

If you want a automated way, suggest you use the build pipeline.  You could **disable the default get source steps** in the build definition. And use your own powershell script to do the get source/pull files to the workspace.  How to, please follow: [Is it able to ignore/disable the first step Get source in vNext Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421482/is-it-able-to-ignore-disable-the-first-step-get-source-in-vnext-build)

This will download files in your build agent, if it's not the machine you are working on. You could combine [Archive Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=vsts) & [Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=vsts) task and select **Scheduled** trigger in your build definition.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickLu-MSFT but it still sounds very complicated and I'm unable to download the code to a folder of my choosing.  I'm very suprised that although its possible to download a zip of the complete code manually, this isn't offered through a command line.  Am still looking into another solution.

Comment: This is the perfect solution (IMO, I guess) to the question.  It's fully automated, and allows you to put the source in a directory of your choice.  @userSteve, if it seems complicated, I suggest you get to know the Azure DevOps interface.  It is MUCH simpler that it seems once you understand the data flow.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing. Bitbucket makes this super easy. Issue a GET to https://bitbucket.org/myusername/myproject/get/branch-name.tar.gz and it downloads it and omits source control binding information. Very straightforward with `curl`; it does not get much easier than this.

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell

```
$tfsurl = "https://tfs.alogent.com/tfs"
$collection ="/defaultcollection"
$project = "/MyProject"
$api = "/_api/_versioncontrol/itemContentZipped?repositoryId=&path="
$path = "$/MyProject/Source/Datafolder"

Invoke-WebRequest -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri "$tfsurl$collection$project$api$path" -OutFile ".\DataFolder.zip"
Expand-Archive .\Datafolder.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

you might consider using an agent + build definition to download the source code (this could happen either based on a schedule or triggered after every check-in). This could easily include compression to a ZIP file and some copy commands.

An additional benefit would be that the build definition doesn't have to re-download the entire source code repository each time it is run - instead, it can be configured to just download get the changes that occurred.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure what you mean by agent definition.  Can you give an example?

Comment: @userSteve: Step 1: [Set up a VSTS Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows). Step 2: [Create a build pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/get-started-designer) (used be called definition until just recently)