# Download test plan artifacts from Azure Devops via command line or Powershell sripts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, test-plan

I would like to download the test plan artifacts (files) from azure devops repository via command line or power shell script. I used this ([Download an application from Azure Devops via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514848/download-an-application-from-azure-devops-via-command-line)) as a reference but I cannot use GIT / repository.

Is there any way I can download the test artifacts (files) for each test case/ test suite via command line or powershell?

Comment: Hi, how the things going? Does the below answer could help you achieve your expected? If yes, you can accept the answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you still facing some issues, feel free to leave comment here :-)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this Rest Api. The download parameter didn't worked as expected.

So there is an another workaround. You can specify the Output file path in the Invoke-RestMethod stage.

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -OutFile D:\1212\test1.txt -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
```