# How to open txt file from Azure DevOps Repo and store it in string?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, repository

I have multiple txt files in specific repository. Would like to take body/content of all these files and store it in List in C# code. How can I get content/body of file from Azure Dev Ops via C# code ?

When I try doing it via code:

```
var buildUrl = $"https://dev.azure.com/CodeRepo/Project/_apis/git/repositories/Indexes/items?path=/server/database/table/index.sql&download=true&versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None&api-version=5.0";

                        using (HttpResponseMessage responseFrom = client.GetAsync(
                              buildUrl).Result)
                        {
                            responseFrom.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                            string responseBody = await responseFrom.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
```

I am getting into result json file:

```
{
    "objectId": "ac759bcb819e39855a7e82a8635d066c50b55555",
    "gitObjectType": "blob",
    "commitId": "da1d095a7cc8193563c9390dc9027aa4b6366333",
    "path": "/server/database/table/index.sql",
    "url": "https://dev.azure.com/CodeRepo/123/_apis/git/repositories/456/items?path=%2server%2Fdatabase%2Ftable%2Findex.sql&versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/CodeRepo/123/_apis/git/repositories/456/items?path=%2Fserver%2Fdatabase%2Ftable%2index.sql&versionType=Branch&versionOptions=None"
        },
        "repository": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/CodeRepo/123/_apis/git/repositories/456"
        },
        "blob": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/CodeRepo/123/_apis/git/repositories/456/blobs/ac759bcb819e39855a7e82a8635d066c50b55555"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the client creation is not represented. I think, you use something like:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Try to remove this header.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rest Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#get-metadata) to get file content. Here is the answer to your question: [Get file from azure devops repository using rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464734/get-file-from-azure-devops-repository-using-rest-api)

Comment: I edit my main post with code example