# TFS 2018 isn't fetching the master branch during Get Sources step

Tags: git, tfs

Git under TFS is failing to retrieve the repo's `master` branch during the initial Get Sources step. The log is below.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Close VS2017
2. Delete the `.git` and `.vs` folders in the solution folder
3. Delete and recreate the repo in TFS
4. Delete all files/folders under `D:\Agent\_work\42\s>` on the agent
5. Open the solution in VS2017, add it to source control (Git)
6. Push the code to the TFS repo (from the only branch, `master`)
7. Verify that the `master` branch exists in the TFS repo
8. Get the logs from the triggered build
9. Note that the `master` branch wasn't synced

In addition, I get this on the agent:

```
D:\Agent\_work\42\s>git branch --list
* (HEAD detached at 09dd4f7)
```

No `master` branch.

This is a brand-new build definition, so I can't say that it was working at some earlier point. This behavior started with the first build. (However it *is* working correctly on other builds, configured exactly the same—albeit created *before* my recent update from 2018.0 to 2018.2.)

How can I make sure the `master` branch gets synced during the initial Get Sources step?

---

```
2018-07-19T01:59:59.3639320Z ##[section]Starting: Get Sources
2018-07-19T01:59:59.4264291Z Syncing repository: Repository (TfsGit)
2018-07-19T01:59:59.4420627Z Prepending Path environment variable with directory containing 'git.exe'.
2018-07-19T01:59:59.4577125Z ##[command]git version
2018-07-19T01:59:59.7829905Z git version 2.17.1.windows.2
2018-07-19T01:59:59.7986389Z ##[command]git config --get remote.origin.url
2018-07-19T02:00:00.0486405Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2018-07-19T02:00:00.4080575Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.http://hostname:1234/tfs/Collection/Project/_git/Repository.extraheader
2018-07-19T02:00:00.7518539Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2018-07-19T02:00:01.0019235Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ********" fetch --tags --prune --progress origin
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote: 
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote:                    fTfs           
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote:                  fSSSSSSSs        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote:                fSSSSSSSSSS        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote: TSSf         fSSSSSSSSSSSS        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote: SSSSSF     fSSSSSSST SSSSS        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote: SSfSSSSSsfSSSSSSSt   SSSSS        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote: SS  tSSSSSSSSSs      SSSSS        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote: SS   fSSSSSSST       SSSSS        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote: SS fSSSSSFSSSSSSf    SSSSS        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote: SSSSSST    FSSSSSSFt SSSSS        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote: SSSSt        FSSSSSSSSSSSS        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote:                FSSSSSSSSSS        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote:                  FSSSSSSs        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote:                    FSFs    (TM)        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote: 
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote:  Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Foundation Server        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9550670Z remote: 
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9706856Z remote: 
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9706856Z remote: Found 280 objects to send. (12 ms)        
2018-07-19T02:00:01.9863268Z warning: no common commits
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0800569Z Receiving objects:   0% (1/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0800569Z Receiving objects:   1% (3/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0800569Z Receiving objects:   2% (6/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0800569Z Receiving objects:   3% (9/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0800569Z Receiving objects:   4% (12/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0800569Z Receiving objects:   5% (14/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:   6% (17/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:   7% (20/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:   8% (23/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:   9% (26/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  10% (28/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  11% (31/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  12% (34/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  13% (37/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  14% (40/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  15% (42/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  16% (45/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  17% (48/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  18% (51/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  19% (54/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  20% (56/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  21% (59/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  22% (62/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  23% (65/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  24% (68/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  25% (70/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  26% (73/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  27% (76/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  28% (79/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  29% (82/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  30% (84/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  31% (87/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  32% (90/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  33% (93/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  34% (96/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  35% (98/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  36% (101/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  37% (104/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  38% (107/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  39% (110/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  40% (112/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  41% (115/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  42% (118/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  43% (121/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  44% (124/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  45% (126/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  46% (129/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  47% (132/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  48% (135/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  49% (138/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  50% (140/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  51% (143/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  52% (146/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  53% (149/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  54% (152/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  55% (154/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  56% (157/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  57% (160/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  58% (163/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  59% (166/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  60% (168/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  61% (171/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  62% (174/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  63% (177/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  64% (180/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  65% (182/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.0956836Z Receiving objects:  66% (185/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  67% (188/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  68% (191/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  69% (194/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  70% (196/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  71% (199/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  72% (202/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  73% (205/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  74% (208/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  75% (210/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  76% (213/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  77% (216/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  78% (219/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  79% (222/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  80% (224/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  81% (227/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  82% (230/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  83% (233/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  84% (236/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  85% (238/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  86% (241/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  87% (244/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  88% (247/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  89% (250/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  90% (252/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  91% (255/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  92% (258/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  93% (261/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  94% (264/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  95% (266/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  96% (269/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  97% (272/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  98% (275/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects:  99% (278/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects: 100% (280/280)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Receiving objects: 100% (280/280), 115.73 KiB | 3.86 MiB/s, done.
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Resolving deltas:   0% (0/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1113091Z Resolving deltas:   1% (3/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:   2% (6/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:   3% (7/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:   5% (12/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:   7% (16/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:   8% (17/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:   9% (19/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:  18% (37/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:  25% (53/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:  34% (70/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:  63% (130/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:  64% (131/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:  75% (153/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:  76% (157/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:  78% (160/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:  81% (166/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas:  95% (195/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas: 100% (204/204)   
2018-07-19T02:00:02.1269327Z Resolving deltas: 100% (204/204), done.
2018-07-19T02:00:02.5650515Z From http://hostname:1234/tfs/Collection/Project/_git/Repository
2018-07-19T02:00:02.5650515Z  + 6efd00e...09dd4f7 master     -> origin/master  (forced update)
2018-07-19T02:00:02.6588093Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force 09dd4f7cf622f3187a7a9a69d39e4ee368d0c205
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3307463Z Warning: you are leaving 2 commits behind, not connected to
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3307463Z any of your branches:
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3307463Z 
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3307463Z   6efd00e Add project files.
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3307463Z   184109a Add .gitignore and .gitattributes.
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3307463Z 
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3307463Z If you want to keep them by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3307463Z to do so with:
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3307463Z 
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3307463Z  git branch <new-branch-name> 6efd00e
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3307463Z 
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3307463Z HEAD is now at 09dd4f7 Add project files.
2018-07-19T02:00:03.3463767Z ##[command]git config http.http://hostname:1234/tfs/Collection/Project/_git/Repository.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: bearer ********"
2018-07-19T02:00:03.4089076Z ##[section]Finishing: Get Sources
```

Comment: Have you tried to  disable the default get source steps in the build definition. And use your own script with git command to do the get source/pull files? This will narrow down the issue. How to please refer  my answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421482/is-it-able-to-ignore-disable-the-first-step-get-source-in-vnext-build

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT — I'll give that a try, thank you. It'll be a few days, but I'll report the results back here.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT — Thanks for checking in. You do a pretty good job of tracking your issues, don't you? But I must inform that I haven't had a chance to try this. Other priorities have taken... priority.

Comment: What's the result if you set the Clean option to "True" in Get Sources step?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT — That's a good question. I'll be working on this again in a few days... I'll try it then.